# No instance for (Generic (f a)) arising from a use of `from'

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, ghc-generics

I'm having issues with finding suitable type constraints for the following code

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import GHC.Generics

data Value = One | Two deriving Generic

class Class a where
    cname :: a -> String -> Bool
    default cname :: (Generic a, GClass (Rep a))
               => a -> String -> Bool
    cname = gname . from

class GClass f where
    gname :: f a -> String -> Bool

instance GClass (f :+: g) where
    gname (L1 x) s | conName (from x) == s = True
                   | otherwise             = False
    gname (R1 x) s | conName (from x) == s = True
                   | otherwise             = False
```

It fails with

```
No instance for (Generic (f a)) arising from a use of `from'
```

Adding the constraint to `gname` like this

```
instance (Generic (f a)) => GClass (f :+: g) where
```

fails with

```
Could not deduce (Generic (f a1)) arising from a use of `from'
from the context (Generic (f a))
```

Edit: The full error message for the full snippet

```
Generic.hs:19:31:
    No instance for (Generic (f a)) arising from a use of `from'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Generic (f a))
    In the first argument of `conName', namely `(from x)'
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely `conName (from x)'
    In the expression: conName (from x) == s

Generic.hs:21:31:
    No instance for (Generic (g a)) arising from a use of `from'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Generic (g a))
    In the first argument of `conName', namely `(from x)'
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely `conName (from x)'
    In the expression: conName (from x) == s
```

This is with GHC 7.6.3

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you get with the posted code? What version of ghc are you using? `Class` and `GClass` both compile fine for me with ghc 7.8.3, but the `GClass` instance for `:+:` fails to compile with different error messages. It's also useful to include more of the error message; there are three occurrences of `from` in the code, and the full error message from ghc would tell which of them doesn't have a the required instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume you are trying to get the constructor names using [`Ghc.Generics`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/GHC-Generics.html). Constructor, field, and data type metadata is held in `M1` nodes. `M1` nodes are tagged with either `D`, `C`, or `S` to indicate whether they hold datatype, constructor, or selector (field) metadata.

I've simplified your `Class` and `GClass` to return the outermost constructor name instead of checking to see if it is a certain name. I'm interpreting `Class` as the class of types whose values have an outermost constructor with a name.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import GHC.Generics

data Value = One | Two deriving Generic

class Class a where
    cname :: a -> String
    default cname :: (Generic a, GClass (Rep a))
               => a -> String
    cname = gname . from

class GClass f where
    gname :: f a -> String
```

We'd like to be able to derive a `Class` instance for `Value` and observe that `cname One == "One"` and `cname Two == "Two"`.

```
instance Class Value    

main = do
    print . cname $ One
    print . cname $ Two
```

We need to implement `GClass` for three of the representation nodes to be able to do this. The representation for `One` is:

```
> from One
M1 {unM1 = L1 (M1 {unM1 = U1})}
```

The outer `M1` is an `M1 D` holding in a dictionary the metadata for the `Value` datatype. The `L1` is selecting the first constructor, `One`. The inner `M1` is an `M1 C` holding in a dictionary the metadata for the `One` constructor. We don't care about anything deeper than it, since that `M1` represents the outermost constructor.

The most interesting node is the inner `M1 C` which holds the constructor metadata. We can get the constructor name as long as the metadata implements the `Constructor` class. The `Constructor` class includes `conName` which returns the constructor name given an appropriate proxy, and the appropriate proxy type is designed to looks like the type of `M1 C`.

```
conName :: Constructor c => t    c (f :: * -> *) a -> [Char]
                            M1 C c  f            p
```

This means we can implement `GClass` simply for `M1 C` nodes as long as there's a `Constructor` instance for the metadata tag `c`

```
instance (Constructor c) => GClass (M1 C c f) where
    gname = conName
```

When we are faced with the choice between two constructors, `:+:`, we can determine the outermost constructor name if we can determine the outermost constructor name of both constructors.

```
instance (GClass f, GClass g) => GClass (f :+: g) where
    gname (L1 x) = gname x
    gname (R1 x) = gname x
```

When we are dealing with a metadata node for a datatype, `M1 D`, we can determine the outermost constructor name when we can determine the outermost constructor name of the representation absent the metadata node.

```
instance GClass f => GClass (M1 D c f) where
    gname (M1 x) = gname x
```

With these three instances we can run our desired code and see that

```
> cname One
"One"
> cname Two
"Two"
```

Comment: Great write up, and this answers my question correctly. Thanks for your help!